# How to update lead stage based on a date/time field?

Tags: trigger

I would like to update leads stage according with a date/time field.

Imagining I have my lead stage as `No Answer (1)` and the date/time field called "Next Stage Change" is `22/12/2015 19:41` how can I do to tomorrow at that time the stage moves to `No Answer (2)` ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use a trigger for this - use a time-based workflow.

Comment: Hello Brian,

Thank you for your prompt answer.

But if I use a time-based workflow the lead stage will only be updated when the lead is edited right?

Thanks

Comment: Rodolfo, no - the time-based workflow is initiated when the Lead is created/edited and meets the criteria; the time-based workflow actions occur at a later point in time (x hours/days after some date value in the Lead )